# Think about stopping the search engine optimization

Tags: discussion

It appears that many, and probably most, of the (many) questions tagged [seo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seo) are blatantly off-topic. Some, however, are not. It's not clear to me that SEO is something we really want to be dealing in anyway. But others may see things differently.

Comment: There is a Webmasters Stack Exchange that seems to deal in SEO questions.  Might help to compare what's considered on-topic there and here.

Comment: There are questions about *implementing* SEO features that are on-topic for Stack Overflow, so it's hard to completely burn the tag. I do agree that many (if not most) questions tagged [tag:seo] are off-topic. I set my Close Votes review queue filter to that tag at least once or twice a week to help clean them up.